# Not Refreshing dependent drop down content dynamically In ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

There is two dependent dropdown one is for country and other for state, state dropdown is rendering based on country. But only first time state drop down is getting value and when we select other country in country dropdown, state dropdown is still showing same values, not refreshing

```
selectState(e){
            let { name, value } = e.target;
            this.setState({ [name]: value });
        }
        async selectCountry(e){
            let { name, value } = e.target;
            this.setState({ [name]: value });
            await this.props.stateData(value);
            this.state.stateList = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('stateList'));
        }


    <div className="form-group row">
                                                <div className="col-md-1"></div>
                                                <div className="col-3"><label className="required" >State</label></div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <select className="stateList" id={'state'} value={this.state.selectedState} onChange={this.selectState} >
                                                        <option key="select" value="select">Select State</option>
                                                        {this.state.stateList &&
                                                        <React.Fragment>
                                                            { this.state.stateList.geoStateNames.map(val =>
                                                               <option key={val.geoId} value={val.geoId}>{val.geoName}</option>
                                                            )}
                                                        </React.Fragment>
                                                        }
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-group row">
                                                <div className="col-md-1"></div>
                                                <div className="col-3"><label className="required" >Country</label></div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <select className="countryList" id={'country'} value={this.state.selectedCountry} onChange={this.selectCountry} >
                                                        <option key="select" value="select">Select Country</option>
                                                        {this.props.countryList &&
                                                        <React.Fragment>
                                                            { this.props.countryList.geoNames.map((val) =>
                                                              <option key={val.geoId} value={val.geoId}>{val.geoName}</option>
                                                            )}
                                                        </React.Fragment>
                                                        }
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
```

Comment: You need to add correct `name` attribute to your `<select>` elements.

Comment: @technophyle Thanks for your reply. Changed name but still not working.

Comment: Please share the updated code.